# What jabber server for personal use?

Tags: software-rec

Using Debian or Ubuntu, what would be the jabber server of choice for small-scale setups?

I mean a setup with probably under 100 user accounts.

Key features:

- sane and secure defaults
- easy and convenient setup
- a good security track-record
- low resource usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pick one from the [server list](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/). Probably jabberd2 is closest to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I've setup and used [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im) with great success in the past.  It has sane defaults, is easy to install (should be available in your package manager) and it is very robust.  On the plus side, as you grow, ejabberd is quite scalable.

Comment: It seems that at least in the past ejabberd had a [problematic default setup regarding remote management ports](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=585122) - which wasn't easy to fix. See also [What is the worst case when the epmd port is open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669834/what-is-the-worst-case-when-the-epmd-port-is-open), although the answers do not mention some of the risks from the bug report.